# Simplifying a fraction, Java

Tags: java

I am doing a school project in which I add 2 fractions and need to simplify the answer. I have a good bit of code so far but there are a few instances where certain fractions do not simplify properly. For instance 1/4+1/6 1ill give 5/6 instead of 5/12. Can you please check my code for any possible errors or for pointers?

```
public int num1, num2, denom1, denom2, numSum, denomAns, denomSimp, gcd;

public Fraction(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6) {
    this.num1 = a1;
    this.num2 = a2;
    this.denom1 = a3;
    this.denom2 = a4;
    this.numSum = a5;
    this.denomAns = a6;
}

public void simplify() {

    if (denom1 == denom2) {
        denomAns = denom1;
        numSum = num1 + num2;
    } else {
        denomAns = denom1 * denom2;
        num1 = num1 * denom2;
        num2 = num2 * denom1;
        numSum = num1 + num2;
    }
    int tempNum = numSum, tempDenom = denomAns;
    if (tempNum == 0) {
        gcd = tempDenom;
    } else {
        while (tempDenom != 0) {
            if (tempNum > tempDenom) {
                tempNum = tempNum - tempDenom;
            } else {
                tempDenom = tempDenom - tempNum;
            }
        }
        gcd = tempNum;
    }
    denomSimp = denomAns / gcd;
    numSum = numSum / gcd;
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried to debug your code?

Comment: Why do you receive the `denomAns`, `denomSimp` and `gcd` in the constructor? Isn't the whole idea of your program is to calculate the last three numbers (some as part of the inner "clockwork")?

Comment: I tested the code with 1/4 and 1/6 and gave me 5/12, https://ideone.com/YR2SoF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package test;

public class Fraction {

    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int denom1;
    private int denom2;

    private int num;
    private int denom;

    public Fraction(int num1, int num2, int denom1, int denom2) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.denom1 = denom1;
        this.denom2 = denom2;
    }

    public void sum() { //sum the two fractions
        num = (num1 * denom2) + (num2 * denom1);
        denom = denom1 * denom2;
    }

    public void simplify() {

        int gcd = gcd(num, denom);

        num = num / gcd;
        denom = denom / gcd;
    }

    public int gcd(int a, int b) {
        return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fraction fraction = new Fraction(1,1,4,6); // 1/4 and 1/6
        fraction.sum();
        fraction.simplify();
        System.out.println("Simplified : " + fraction.getNumSimp() + "/" + fraction.getDenomSimp());
    }

    public int getNumSimp() {
        return num;
    }

    public int getDenomSimp() {
        return denom;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.